# VB.Net Jumps to a wrong return statement within Select Case

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that tests if a given Value is okay. In this Function different Cases are Handled, 2 of which always Return True or False, the third one only does a Return when the Value is not OK. If the Value is OK in this case, there's a 'Return True' after the Select.

The thing is, after executing that Case block, the debugger doesn't go to End Select but back to a Return Statement in that Case Block.

It's Easy to avoid this by just putting the last "Return True" into said Case-Block. I just wonder why this happens, since i couldn't find any such exceptions in the MSDN page.

```
Private Function IsValueOK(ByVal Value As String, ByVal Type As Integer) As Boolean
    Select Case Type
        Case 1 : Return (Value = "True")
        Case 3 : Return Value.Contains("|*|True")
        Case 2
            Dim NominalValue As Double? = ... '10
            Dim UpperTolerance As Double? = ... '0.1
            Dim lowerTolerance As Double? = ... '-0.1
            Dim Digits As Integer = ... '2

            If NominalValue.HasValue AndAlso IsNumeric(Value) Then
                Dim Part As Double = Math.Round(CDbl(Value), Digits)
                If UpperTolerance.HasValue AndAlso Part > Math.Round(NominalValue + UpperTolerance, Digits) Then Return False
                If lowerTolerance.HasValue AndAlso Part < Math.Round(NominalValue + lowerTolerance, Digits) Then Return False
            Else
                Return False
            End If
    End Select
    Return True
End Function
```

Value is "9.9" and Type is 2.

In this scenario the first if-statement is true So the debugger goes into the If-Block, the second and third If-Statements are False, so no Return-Statement is executed and the debugger correctly jumps into the "End If" Line. But after that, I'd expect it to Jump to End Select. Instead, it jumps to 'Return False' in the Line above.

**Edit:**
After some further testing with different builds (even clean release builds) this occurs almost randomly. I'm getting the impression, that the compiler is having some instability that is somehow exploited by the Projects context. I'm going with not Mixing *Cases that definitely return stuff* and *Cases that might return stuff*.

**Edit 2:** 
In the meantime, I realised that my release build tests have not been representable - That means I found said behaviour only while debugging. This frees the compiler of my premature accusations about instability ^^"

btw: I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: It shouldn't be jumping around like that. Did you properly clean\rebuild the whole solution?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this functionality or even understand how it's occuring for you

Comment: I too don't seem to get the question but try rebuilding your solution.

Comment: Don't you miss a break in your second case for if non off the inner ifs will match? Vb.net does has break in switch, no?

Comment: To my knowledge vb.net does not have 'break' in Cases.

Comment: I can reproduce your observed behavior. You have to realize that the compiler converts your code to IL code that is in turned compiled. While it is valid to have multiple return points in IL code, it is my observation that the compiler was written to produce methods with a single return point. As a consequence of a single return point, the return value is assigned to a compiler defined local variable that is ultimately returned by the method. This along with other re-orderings can cause a disconnect in order between your written code and the executing code while observed while debugging.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats the Answer to my question: "I wonder why this happens". I'd mark it as Answer, if it wasn't a comment ;)

Comment: @TnTinMn: I do not understand. Are you stating that the compiler might contain bugs that would produce a result that does not match the original code if that code contains multiple returns?? (I have never observed that behavior before. It would be very alarming, I guess.)

Comment: @BartHofland, No, I said nothing about it being a compiler bug.  The compiler is free to restructure code as long as such restructuring does not alter result.  All I meant was that sometimes this restructuring and the debuggers attempt to map the executing code back to the original source is not 100% accurate.  This mapping issue has been observed before; a common issue is some exception at line X, but it should be at line X ± a line or two.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Ah. I see. Then I am calmed again. :) I have noticed the issue regarding the wrong line once, but I thought it was a VS bug. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: @TnTinMn: Could that cause the wrong line to be executed, hence returning a "false" where a "true" should have been returned? It sounds like VS would only highlight the wrong line, but in that case, the function should have returned True. However, it actually did return False.

Comment: You appear to have a logic error in your tolerances.  I believe one of the arithmetic operations should be a `-` instead of a `+` (by inspection, I think it's the first one involving `UpperTolerance`).  And as I look further, this might also be why you're not getting the result you expect.

Comment: Also, on a more general note, be very careful with floating point comparisons involving decimal numbers that don't have an exact representation.  You can get unexpected inequalities or comparisons in these cases (e.g. you mention a value of 9.9 against an expected of 10 with tolerance of 0.1, neither 9.9 nor 0.1 is exactly representable and you're right at the boundary, so you could get unexpected results solely due to the vagaries of the behavior of binary floating point math.

Comment: "Could that cause the wrong line to be executed, hence returning a "false" where a "true" should have been returned?" - As a general rule, No as that would definitely be a bug.  That's not to say that bugs do not occur and if you believe you found one, please definitely report it with full reproducing code.  More likely, the issue is floating point inaccuracies as mentioned by @Craig or some other logic fault in your code.